# How to map a line into circle

Tags: geometry

Is there any transformation mapping a line of length l into a circle of radius r such that $l = 2\pi*r$?

Comment: Basically, I want to bend a line into a circle such that the length of line becomes perimeter of circle.

Comment: yes, define the map $f: [0,l] \to \mathbb{R}^2: t \mapsto (r\cos(2\pi t/l), r\sin(2\pi t/l))$ with $r = l/2\pi$. The image is a circle of radius $r$.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

Consider a circle on a sphere which is passing through a the North Pole of the sphere.

Use stereographic projection technique, to map every point on a circle (other than north pole) to a plane. Image of these points lying on the straight line. Also, it is a bijection.

(But there is one point on the circle that is North Pole does not map with any point).

Edit:
Assume the radius of sphere =$r$.
North pole= $(0,0,0)$

Comment: This is not right. The OP wants to map **a line of finite length** onto a circle. This technique maps **the full real line** onto a circle (except for the North Pole).

Comment: Yes sir. The above map is inversible also. And the OP asking "into map". That's why I am answering like this.

Comment: Oh yes I got it. Here, the problem is on line segment.

Comment: yes, a line segment is being mapped to circle.

Comment: I mean, this is a valid technique, but it maps a line segment to an arc, not to a full circle.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thus it is not an answer for this question. How can I delete my answer? Is it necessary to delete my answer? Sir.

Comment: what is the mapping function for mapping to an arc instead of circle?

Comment: @snano Just a map a north pole to any one of the point on straight line. Thus we got the map from a circle to a straight line. But it is not a one-to-one function.

Comment: It is not necessary to delete the answer, if you ask me. The question is not very precise, actually, and if you want a mapping of a line *into* a circle, then it is perfectly good. Leave it there, it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and here’s one way to do this. Assume the line is on the $x$ axis. First map the domain of the line to $[0,2\pi]$ by enforcing an affine map $f$. Then  map $[0,2\pi]$ to the circle of radius $r$ using the map $g: \theta \to (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. The composition $g \cdot f$ does the trick.

Comment: works fine. A suggestion of any standard book related to similar stuff would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can this mapping be modified to an arc instead of circle by changing angle $2pi$ to angle $\theta$?

Comment: Not sure about any books. Basically the idea is how can I parametrize a circle? Natural way is using $\theta$ as a parameter? Next... how can I relate the length of my line to $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$? That’s not too hard...

Comment: Also yes, if you first enforce the mapping $D$ to $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$. Then enforce $\theta \to (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$, you’ll get a $45$ degree arc.

Comment: All this works; but when looking in a practical sense, I mean line, say a rod, has some width. So, the problem becomes two dimensional. That rod has length ($l$) and width($w$). Then, I suppose the same mapping would work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple geometric approach: do the projection from point on circle the farthest from line. E.g.,  let your line be x axis, and your circle be a unit circle with center at [0, 0.5]. Now draw the line from point [0, 1] of the circle through every other point of that circle until it intersects with x axis, and you "unfolded" circle into the line. Reverse the process and you "fold" it back into circle.

Answer (score -1):

$$ s= r \theta , \theta =s/r $$

For a full closed circle radius R of perimeter length $ 2 \pi R $ at each arc length $s$..

$$ x=R \sin (s/R); y=  R (1-\cos (s/R)) $$

We start with a flat line, left end fixed at the origin. We change center angle as well as the radius of curvature preserving arc length product same. Done by increasing subtended angle at  arc / sector center and decreasing radius of curvature.

The map is a limited *"path isometry,"* a mapping function could be defined..

The bent arc ( the tip locus traces out a cardoid like curve not shown here.)

Keeping the same arc-length through factor p, $ l =  2 \pi r, r=1/p $ is maintained constant at each bent configuration as shown:

EDIT1:

`Mathematica` code includes animation of bending phenomenon, forwards and backwards. (line curls up to circle and flattens back to a line).

$$x=(r/p) \sin (s/r); y=  (r/p) (1-\cos (s/r)); 0<p<1 ; $$

Btw,in Mechanics of materials it is a realization of Euler- Bernoulli bending Law $ EI \kappa = M $ where bending moment M increases curvature $ \kappa$, EI being the elastic constant/ bending rigidity.

[image]